# Express app - Execute function on many but not all requests

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

What is the best way to call a function on many but not all requests in a node express app? (An example would be a function which checks if the user is currently logged in)

What I did is to define a module exporting a `checkLogin(...)` function and to call this function on each corresponding api-request. E.g.:

Module auth:

```
module.exports = {
    checkLogin: function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.session.hasOwnProperty('user')) {
            //if the user is logged in we pass through
            next();
        } else if (req.cookies.user == undefined || req.cookies.pass == undefined) {
            res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
        } else {
            User.checkLogin(req.cookies.user, req.cookies.pass, true, function(o) {
                if (o != null) {
                    req.session.user = o;
                    next();
                } else {
                    res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Routes for /index:

```
//...
var auth = require('../middlewares/auth.js');
//...
    router.get('/index', auth.checkLogin, function(req, res) {

        //if we passed the auth.checkLogin step we render the index page
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Index',
            udata: req.session.user
        });

    });
```

In another route file:

```
//...
var auth = require('../middlewares/auth.js');
//...
        router.get('/user/someAPICall', auth.checkLogin, function(req, res) {
           ...
        });
```

Is this the way to go or are there better ways to do that? I could define a middleware function which I could include using `app.use(function(){..})` in each route. The problem is that every request for this route would go through this function which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) are a great way to design your application. You could think of your URL paths as namespaces, and create a router for the namespace that requires user authentication.
*Most likely your main `/index` page won't require immediate redirecting to login, since it's used for presentation purposes; but if required, then just include the `auth.checkLogin` as you did above.*

For everything else where you need your user to be authenticated (e.g. everything under `/user/*`), you'd better create a scoped router

```
const router = express.Router();
router.use(auth.checkLogin);
router.get('/someAPICall', fn1, fn2);
router.get('/someOtherAPICall', fn3, fn4);
```

and then in your parent router or main app, just include the router:

```
app.use('/user', router);
```

which is just like defining:

```
app.use('/user/someAPICall', [auth.checkLogin, fn1, fn2]);
app.use('/user/someOtherAPICall', [auth.checkLogin, fn3, fn3]);
```

This gives you the advantage of creating modular route handlers - which makes them easier to adjust, reuse, etc. - and at the same time will keep `auth.checkLogin`, although always executed when the router is entered, just for the paths defined by the router.

In short, the approach would be: "execute function on all routes inside the router, but not on *all* the app requests".

If you cannot redesign your routes in this way, then yes, you'll always need to include `auth.checkLogin` in handlers list for the paths you only want to use.